# Test class not working for the Cloud_News__e Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Whats wrong in the below test class? Why its not going inside the for `(Cloud_News__e event : Trigger.New)` ?

```
@isTest
public class PlatformEventTest {
    @isTest
    static void test1(){
        Cloud_News__e newsEvent = new Cloud_News__e(
            Location__C = 'Mountain City', 
            Urgent__c=true, 
            News_Content__c='Test message.');

        Test.startTest();
        Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(newsEvent);
        Test.stopTest();

        List<Case> cases = [select Id from Case];
        System.assertEquals(1, cases.size());
    }
}
```

and Trigger

```
// Trigger for listening to Cloud_News events.
trigger CloudNewsTrigger on Cloud_News__e (after insert) {    
    // List to hold all cases to be created.
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();

    // Get queue Id for case owner
    Group queue = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name='Regional Dispatch' LIMIT 1];

    // Iterate through each notification.
    for (Cloud_News__e event : Trigger.New) {
        if (event.Urgent__c == true) {
            // Create Case to dispatch new team.
            Case cs = new Case();
            cs.Priority = 'High';
            cs.Subject = 'News team dispatch to '+event.Location__c;
            cs.OwnerId = queue.Id;
            cases.add(cs);
        }
   }

    // Insert all cases corresponding to events received.
    insert cases;
}
```

and image ?

[image]

### EDIT:

Seems like something is breaking

```
08:41:46.0 (184929389)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[22]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
08:41:46.0 (185214254)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[22]|Bytes:117
08:41:46.0 (185294122)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Trigger.CloudNewsTrigger: line 22, column 1
08:41:46.0 (185323839)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No group is found, so the query is crashing with "no rows for assignment." Create a new Group in your unit test first.

```
@isTest
public class PlatformEventTest {
    @isTest
    static void test1(){
        Cloud_News__e newsEvent = new Cloud_News__e(
            Location__C = 'Mountain City', 
            Urgent__c=true, 
            News_Content__c='Test message.');
        // create a new group.
        insert new Group(Name='Regional Dispatch',DeveloperName='Regional_Dispatch');
        Test.startTest();
        Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(newsEvent);
        Test.stopTest();

        List<Case> cases = [select Id from Case];
        System.assertEquals(1, cases.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but still test case fails with error :  System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1, Actual: 0

Comment: @user4567570 It probably crashed on the last line (insert cases). You'll probably want to make sure you're not missing any required fields, etc. Check your debug logs from when you run the test. Use the Developer Console's Log tab to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Its failing for insert only.. I will try to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to look in the save result in your test for a reason by adding e.g.:

```
Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(newsEvent);
System.assert(sr.isSuccess(), String.valueOf(sr.getErrors()));
```

(If a failure is being returned, you may have to improve the output of the error information.)

**PS**

Suggest you comment out the `Group` query and `cs.OwnerId = queue.Id` assignment from your trigger temporarily and see what happens. The problem may be that the assignment from the `Group` query is failing because no rows are being returned but the error is not being surfaced.

Comment: NO, nothing is happening, still the same code coverage.

Comment: @user4567570 If you are saying that `sr.isSuccess()` is true, suggest you add that clarification to your question.

Comment: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1, Actual: 0